# sending bit shifted data over serial port

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have 2 processors: A and B. A is decoding a 4x4 keypad and sending the characters to processor B which drives a display. Processor A also has real-time data that it sends to B. So I want a scheme where A filters out the data from the keypresses. A will also send a special code which tells B that the next 1 or 2 bytes are data for the display. The keypad chars will handle menuing. I was thinking that if I sent anything with the msb set: 0xFF to 0x80 - then B would filter that out as either a keypress or a special code. So the data would be by preceded by (for instance) 0xFF - sending a parameter 1 as a byte and 0xFE - sending parameter 2 as a word. The data for the byte would be shifted to the right 1 bit so B would interpret that as 0-127 in even numbers. When sending a word, it would have to be 2 bytes representing a word but each byte is shifted over 1 bit so the resulting word would end up being shifted over 2 bits (0->16,383 in multiples of 4), which is accurate enough for the display. I'm trying to do this using bit shifting for sending a word (uint16_t):

```
uint16_t decode(UCHAR num1, UCHAR num2)
{
    uint16_t res;
    num1 <<= 1;
    num2 <<= 1;
    num1 |= ((num2 >> 7) & 1);
    res = (uint16_t)(num1 << 8) | ((num2 << 1) & 0x7f);
    return res;
}

void encode(UCHAR *num1, UCHAR *num2, uint16_t res)
{
    UCHAR temp1, temp2;
    uint16_t tres = res >> 2;
    temp1 = (UCHAR)res;
    temp2 = (UCHAR)(res >> 8);
    temp1 >>= 1;
    temp2 >>= 1;
    *num1 = (temp1 & 0x7f);
    *num2 = (temp2 & 0x7f);
}
for(res = 0;res < 0xffff;res++)
{
    encode(&num1,&num2,res);
    res2 = decode(num1,num2);
    printf("%d -> %x %x\n",res, num1, num2);
}
```

I know this is not quite right but I'm wondering if it would be easier to do this using unions or bit-fields.

Comment: Out of interest, how come you're creating a new protocol rather than using e.g. RS-232/ USB/ IEEE 802.* (Ethernet) etc?

Comment: Its just a standard serial port (RS-232)

Comment: Right ok, it's unclear what all the shifting is actually trying to achieve considering RS-232 will transfer any arbitrary byte for you (it came across as describing a [shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register) which are used to create 'custom' serial protocols).

Comment: both processors have the capabilities of 9-bit - maybe that would be easier.